# Making a Vega.js gradient legend wider

Tags: d3.js, vega

I am trying to modify the Vega.js choropleth example to use a gradient legend, and then to make that legend wider. I have succeeded in changing the type to "gradient", but when I try to make the legend wider, the text labels remain stuck and do not widen with the color bar.

Here's a link to the full code: https://jsbin.com/tamenucohu/edit?html,output

Here is the legend-specific part:

```
"legends": [
  {
    "fill": "color",
    "orient": "bottom-right",
    "title": "Unemployment",
    "format": "0.1%",
    "type": "gradient",
    "encode": {
      "gradient": {
        "update": {
          "width": {"value": 300}
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Here's a screenshot when I set the width to 300, note that the "0.0%" and "15.0%" text labels are not properly spaced: [wider color bar with narrower labels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VTDjT.png)